# Show that a prime p divides $a^p - a$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime. I want to show that $p | a^p - a$. I want to use induction.

I showed that this is true for the case $a = 1$. I'm having trouble with the bridge.

Comment: If possible, I just want a hint, not a solution.

Comment: Is this not equivalent to Fermat's little theorem?

Comment: That was my thought. I'm just drawing a blank for how to prove it.

Comment: Do you already have Fermat's little theorem in your arsenal? Or are you disallowed from using that?

Comment: This would be too trivial to prove with fermat's little theorem I think. I believe he is attempting to prove fermat's little theorem itself.

Comment: Don't think I'm supposed to use Fermat.

Comment: @GaMbiT In that case, go with pMarkov's answer.

Comment: See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/829851/proof-check-for-fermats-little-theorem), [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/686941/fermats-little-theorem-proof-by-euler) and many other places.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: We assumed $a^p \equiv a \pmod{p}$

Consider the Binomial expansion of: $(a+1)^p$ :

$(a+1)^p = a^p + {p \choose 1} a^{p-1} + {p \choose 2} a^{p-2} + \cdots + {p \choose p-1} a + 1.$

Now see how you can reduce this expression into something much simpler, where you can apply the assumption. You may not use the assumption until the end.

(comment if you would like further help!)